# Insert using GridMVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do an insert using a GridMVC column.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    @Html.Grid(@Model.OrderBy(i=>i.Sequence)).Columns(columns =>
    {
        if (columns != null)
        {
            columns.Add(c => c.Sequence).Titled("SEQUENCE").Filterable(true);
            columns.Add(c => c.Desc).Titled("DESC").Filterable(true);
            columns.Add().Titled("")
                .Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(10).RenderValueAs(m =>
                    @<b>
                    <button type="button" class="action btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="modal" data-grupo="@m.group" data-subgrupo="@m.thing" data-id="@m.avaliation" data-target="#myModal"></button>
                    </b>);

            columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(2).RenderValueAs(m => @<b>
                @Html.DropDownList(m.Id.ToString(), new SelectList(m.punctuationList.OrderBy(i => i.Punctuation), "Punctuation", "Punctuation"), new { style = "width: 85px;", @class = "form-control ", required = "required" })
                </b>);
            columns.Insert(...)           
        }
    }).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).WithMultipleFilters()

</div>
```

I want to do an insert using the last column, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Actually was not how I was thinking.

```html
   <div class="col-lg-12">
            @Html.Grid(@Model.OrderBy(i=>i.Sequence)).Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                            
                                            if (columns != null)
                                            {
                                                columns.Add(c => c.Sequence).Titled("SEQUENCE").Filterable(true);
                                                columns.Add(c => c.Desc).Titled("DESC").Filterable(true);
                                                columns.Add().Titled("Oportunity")
                                                    .Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(10).RenderValueAs(m =>
                                                        @<b>
                                                              @Html.TextArea("txt_Oportunity"+m.Id, "", new {@class = "form-control"})
                                                        </b>);
                                                columns.Add().Titled("")
                                                     .Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(10).RenderValueAs(m =>
                                                    @<b>
                                                    <button type="button" class="acao btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="modal" data-grupo="@m.grupo" data-subgrupo="@m.subgrupo" data-id="@m.OrientacaoAvaliacao" data-target="#myModal"></button>
                                                    </b>);
                                                columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(2).RenderValueAs(m => @<b>
                    @Html.DropDownList(m.Id.ToString(), new SelectList(m.PunctuationList.OrderBy(i => i.Punctuation), "Punctuation", "Punctuation"), new { style = "width: 85px;", @class = "form-control ", required = "required" })
                </b>);
                                            }
                                        }).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).WithMultipleFilters()
        </div>
```

Is not necessary to use a specifies property 'insert'. I used a @Html.TextArea to get my "txt_Oportunity" and passed it to my controller. Hope that help!